# Any student/student(s)

Tags: grammar, determiners

Are the following sentences correct? As an English speaker or an teacher would you prefer a singular noun or a plural noun after **any** in the following sentences? I admit I have asked many questions regarding **any**. Still I have some doubts.

- If **any student is** interested in joining the programme, he or she is requested to contact the authority.
- If **any students are** interested in joining the programme, they are requested to contact the authority.
- **Any student** interested in joining the programme **is** requested to contact the authority.
- **Any students** interested in joining the programme **are** requested to contact the authority.

I have noticed that **any** can be used with both singular and plural nouns. But when **any** is used with **if** and in questions like the avove, should I use a plural noun or a singular noun?

Please confirm as an English speaker or as an English teacher which one you would prefer.

Comment: Could you add more detail to explain why you feel this is confusing?  Perhaps include whatever research you might have done?   Otherwise this question may be closed.

Comment: @Andrew As a non native English speaker, I have doubts about the usage of "any"from the beginning. I have asked many questions regarding usage of " any" on this site. If anyone tells me or explain which of the above sentences the person prefers, I will stick to that pattern of the sentences.

Comment: @Andrew Hi, I have added as much details as I can. I am not able to put more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Any" can be used with either a singular or a plural noun.

> Any is a determiner. It generally suggests an indefinite amount or number, and is used when it is not important to say how much/ how many we are thinking of. Because of its "open," non-specific meaning, any is often used in questions and negative clauses and in other cases where there is an idea of doubt or negation  [(source)](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00294.html)

It's the same in an "if" clause.  It depends on who you are talking to, and what you want to say.  For example, all of the following are valid:

> (Addressing a group of multiple people, asking for a single idea) *If you (plural) have **any idea** how to find Waldo, let me know.*
>
> (Addressing a group of multiple people, asking for a non-specific number of ideas) *If you (plural) have **any ideas** on how to find Waldo, let me know.*
>
> (Single person, single idea) *If you (singular) have **any idea** how to find Waldo, let me know.*
>
> (Single person, multiple ideas) *If you (singular) have **any ideas** on how to find Waldo, let me know.*

Note the difference in phrasing.  If I want a single idea, I specify the idea (*an* idea how to ...).  If I want multiple ideas, I instead have to specify the general topic (some ideas *on* how to ...

In your examples, you're asking the same question from a slightly different perspective:

> *If any student is interested* ... (= "a particular type of student, of which there can be an unspecified number")
>
> *If any students are interested* ... (= "some unspecified number of a particular type of student")

Both are fine, however there may be a slight difference in nuance as the singular might emphasize these individuals have some *unique* quality.  For example, imagine a drill instructor talking to a group of new soldiers:

> If **any recruit** is man enough -- or dumb enough -- to try and beat my time on the obstacle course, step forward now.

Depending on the intonation, this can be seen as a challenge to some especially brave recruit.  The plural might instead be considered a challenge to the entire group:

> If **any of you recruits** are man enough ...